# How to handle unexpected client disconnects on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a AspNetCore 3.1 server and a number of WinForms clients connect to its SignalR hub. In my hub, I do the following:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, someConnectionInfo);
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, someConnectionInfo);
    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

On the client side of things I call the hub connection's `Connect` and `Disconnect` as required. This all works fine in normal circumstances.

But what happens if the client terminates unexpectedly without the possibility to disconnect from the hub?

If the server calls a client method by doing:

```
await hubContext.Clients.All.ClientMethod();
```

Will `All` also contain the client that terminated unexpectedly? Is there a way to know which clients are still connected?

Comment: If you look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-handle-connection-lifetime-events-in-the-hub-class ,OnDisconnected is called when client looses the connection permanently. so if client terminates , it's connection is lost from server as well . If you need to check if connection exist you can use Linq on hubContext.Clients ->this contains all connected clients.

Comment: If your client is terminated and the server still decides to push to the client, it will fail at transport -> say the connection is not available to push the data. With older Signalr it would have been pushed to ring buffer if the connection still exists.